# Google Maps API Reports Error and Does Not Work

Tags: wordpress, google-maps

Ever since Google required an API for the Maps I've had nothing but trouble and I still cannot get it to work. Way to wreck something that worked perfectly fine, Google.

I am now pulling out my hair.

I have a Wordpress site.

I applied for an API key for the Maps on https://console.developers.google.com under Credentials.

I installed the Google Maps API KEY Wordpress plugin and added the key https://wordpress.org/plugins/api-key-for-google-maps/

It works for 5 minutes and then reverts back to "This page can't load Google Maps correctly."

Can any tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Rich95,

There are different possible causes of the issue:

- The API Key has not been configured correctly, for example, if the "HTTP Referrers" in the "Application Restrictions" section does not cover the URL where the map is inserted.
- The APIs enabled with your project in the Google Console are not the required ones for the features in your map.
- Your website is loading multiple instances of the Google Maps Library.
  etc.

Please, indicate the URL to the webpage where the map is inserted.